# When to close the ark after putting away the Torah

Tags: minhag, song-poetry, torah-service, ark-aron-kodesh, opening-the-ark

On shabbat morning when putting away the Torah, many chazzanim like to draw out different tunes for the verses recited then. Should the one honored with putting the Torah back wait until after the singing to close the ark? Should he close it when he's done putting the Torah back? Should he half close it, and complete the closing when the chazzan is finished? I have seen all three of these options done. Which is most popular/preferable?

Comment: What I've seen in the two congregations I frequent (one for Shabbat, one for weekdays) is that the curtain gets closed right after the scroll is put away and the doors get closed at the end of the singing.  I don't know why (which is why this is a comment and not an answer).

Comment: Is there a reason to think that it matters?  Although my Rav was makpid that uvnucho yomar should be done simultaneously with putting the Torah in the ark.  It shouldn't be started while the shatz is carrying it.

Comment: @YDK No particular reason why it matters. I was doing it last shabbat and wasn't sure if there should be some preference.

Comment: @YDK Just as a thought, you might think that Kevod haTorah dictates not leaving it open needlessly, or perhaps not leaving it open when it is not for the Torah's needs but ours. Alternatively, you might feel that saying those pesukim needs to happen while it is open (I have no idea why you would say that though).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the ark kept open until the singing is concluded.

The Koren Siddur says that the ark should be closed after the u'vnucho yomar verses are concluded. It shouldn't really make a difference whether they are being said quickly or drawn out.